# Ansible notify restart when a file changed

Tags: ansible, handler

I try to restart a docker for specific item on inventory (aa,bb) when the file changed with copy module. If the copy changed the file so it trigger a handler to restart the specific item. The copy works but the handler is never trigger.

instances.yml

```yaml
instances:
  aa:
    name: "aa"
  bb:
    name: "bb"
```

playbook.yml

```yaml
- name: Copy config
  copy:
    src: "roles/{{ item.value.name }}.yaml"
    dest: "etc/{{ item.value.name }}.yaml"
  with_dict: "{{ instances1 }}"
  register: template
  notify:
    - my_handler
```

handlers/main.yml

```yaml
- name: my_handler
  shell: "notify {{ item.key }}"
  with_items: "{{ template.results | selectattr('changed', 'equalto', true) | map(attribute='item')| list }}"
```

Comment: are you using roles?

Comment: yes I am using,

Comment: i have no problem. could you show your structure role with folder and file?

Comment: @frenchy I edit the question and add the structure of my file

Comment: The fact that your file called `inventory.yml` is actually not an inventory is a bit missleading. The file structure inside your `roles/profile` subdir does not exactly look like a role. You pasted the content of a `task.yml` file that is not present in your structure.... Please edit your question and make the above a correct [MCVE](/help/mcve). Thanks.

Comment: @Zeitounator Indeed, I correct it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A functional sample:

```
/my_project
|playbook.yml
|--/roles
|  |--/test
|     |--/tasks
|     |   main.yml
|     |
|     |--/handlers
|     |   main.yml
|     |
|     |--/files
|     |   aa.yaml
|     |   bb.yam
```

playbook.yml

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  roles:
    - test
```

In folder `my_project/roles/test/tasks`: main.yml

```yaml
- name: Copy config
  copy:
    src: "{{ item.value.name }}.yaml"
    dest: "zzz{{ item.value.name }}.txt"
  with_dict: "{{ instances }}"
  register: template
  vars:
    instances:
      aa:
        name: "aa"
      bb:
        name: "bb"
  notify:
    - my_handler

- name: Force all notified handlers to run at this point, not waiting for normal sync points
    meta: flush_handlers
```

In folder `my_project/roles/test/handlers`: main.yml

```yaml
- name: my_handler
  debug:
    msg: notify called {{ item }}
  with_items: "{{ template.results | selectattr('changed', 'equalto', true) | map(attribute='item')| list }}"
```

Result:

```
RUNNING HANDLER [test : my_handler] 
ok: [localhost] => (item={'key': 'aa', 'value': {'name': 'aa'}}) => {
    "msg": "notify called {'key': 'aa', 'value': {'name': 'aa'}}"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item={'key': 'bb', 'value': {'name': 'bb'}}) => {
    "msg": "notify called {'key': 'bb', 'value': {'name': 'bb'}}"
}
```

to execute Handlers at once add task `meta: flush_handlers`

Comment: @teerrrzi a handler is triggered only when a task reports `changed`. On the second deployment the file already exists with the same content, the copy task reports `ok` and nothing is triggered.

Comment: yes it works with you project, but not mine, I add the structure of my playbook

Comment: @Frenchy I have a clue, When I delete the other tasks after the first module, the handlers works, but when I have a multiple name module after handlers, the handler is not triggered. Because the handlers is triggered at the end of task. So how to triggered immedialty the handler before to go execute the left of playbook.yml

Comment: ist the default setting for handlers,   see my answer...to notify at once handlers, add task meta: flush

Comment: yes it works with that, thank you very much. There is another solution

Comment: ah I know why, is not working, because on my playbook I execute also a multiple register: template, so the value is not changed because the block is no changed, and at the end the handler is not triggered